# Asymptotic expansion of Hypergeometric2F1[1, m, 1 + m, 2] as $m$ goes to infinity.

Tags: asymptotics, hypergeometric-function

I would like to get an asymptotic expansion of 
$$
\, _2F_1(1,m;m+1;2)
$$
as
$m \to \infty$.

I have checked DLMF (https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.12), but I have not found anything that may be used for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your function is defined by the standard reflection formula, then
$$F(m) = {_2F_1}(1, m; m + 1; 2) =\\
(-2)^{-m} \pi m \csc \pi m -
 \frac m {2(m - 1)} \,{_2F_1} \left( 1, 1 - m; 2 - m; \frac 1 2 \right) = \\
(-2)^{-m} \pi m \csc \pi m -
 \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac 1 {1 - \frac {k + 1} m} 2^{-k - 1}.$$
Let $m$ be bounded away from integers by some fixed distance. Then the first term is exponentially small and can be discarded.

The summand will decrease exponentially in $k$, with $(1 - (k + 1)/m)^{-1}$ staying bounded. Then we can expand the summand into a series in $m$ to obtain a complete asymptotic series for $F(m)$:
$$F(m) \sim -\sum_{k = 0}^\infty
 \operatorname{Li}_{-k} \left( \frac 1 2 \right) m^{-k} =
-1 - \frac 2 m - \frac 6 {m^2} - \dots \,.$$
$F(m)$ is, in fact, continuous, the integral values of $m$ are removable singularities.

Comment: Where does the reflection formula come from? The $\mathrm{csc}$ term is surprising to me here. Is there a link somewhere on DLMF? I don't see a formula like this